# Convert XML to JSON in Python by validating against schema

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml

I want to convert XMLs to JSON format. I found many packages(xmltodict) to do that in python, but when there is only one element in a node it is converting that to a dictionary but according to the schema I have, even if there is only one element it should be placed in a list.
For ex:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <name> bookName </name>
  </book>
</books>
```

The expected output is:

```
 "books":[{
      "book":[{
           "name" : "bookName"
}]
}]
}
```

The current output that I'm getting is:

```
{
"books":
    {
    "book":
        { 
        "name" : "bookName" 
        }
    }
}
```

This happens only when there is only a single element. I am trying to find a way to convert the xml to json by validating against the json schema I have. I tried using DECLXML package, but it is creating empty array when the node is not there in the xml. It would be very helpful if someone can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your example has single `<book>` record and just one `name` as an information about your book. Hence, your code didn't create lists in the output JSON.

Did you try to use `xmltodict` module as an alternative way?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-xml-to-json/

Comment: I tried used xmltodict module, but it was not working for my scenario. There is a parameter force_list, in which I can pass the elements which should be created as list in output json. Since my input xml is huge and has many nested nodes, it was not useful